# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor task removal from queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task with a fixed delay and want to have just one task in the queue of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. My thought is to use `getQueue().isEmpty()` to check if there is only one task in the queue.

I know that the task remains in the queue until the fixed delay. I need to know exactly when the task is removed from the queue. I assume that it is removed when the task start to execute the runnable command. However I could not find any spec that says so exactly.

Here is the code I envision:

```
if (task.getQueue().isEmpty()){
        task.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                 // do my awesome stuff
            }
        }, FIXED_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

So this way only one task can be scheduled in the queue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? What are you trying to achieve and why? Do you want to schedule another task once the initial task starts executing?

Comment: task is not automatically
> removed from the work queue until its delay elapses

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? I smell an X/Y-Problem.

Comment: @Niels, Exactly, I do not want to run the same task again if it was already scheduled before and in the queue. Updated the post

Comment: how many different tasks could you have in your  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor? If more than one, how do you distinguish that it is the same task as a task previously scheduled?

Comment: only once task should be in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
publicinterface ConflictingRunnable extends Runnable {
    boolean hasConflicts(Runnable other);
}
```

And

```
public class ConflictAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final Map<Runnable, ScheduledFuture> scheduledRunnables = new HashMap<>();

    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public ConflictAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command,
                                       long delay,
                                       TimeUnit unit) {
        if (command instanceof ConflictingRunnable) {
            final ConflictingRunnable conflictingRunnable = (ConflictingRunnable) command;
            for (final Iterator<Runnable> itt = scheduledRunnables.keySet().iterator(); itt.hasNext(); ) {
                final Runnable scheduledRunnable = itt.next();
                final ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledRunnables.get(scheduledRunnable);
                if (scheduledFuture.isDone()) {
                    itt.remove();
                } else if (conflictingRunnable.hasConflicts(scheduledRunnable)) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        final ScheduledFuture<?> t = this.executor.schedule(command, delay, unit);
        scheduledRunnables.put(command, t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

When you run:

```
public class ScheduledTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        final ConflictAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor conflictAwareScheduler = new ConflictAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(scheduler);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            conflictAwareScheduler.schedule(new MyTask(i), 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        scheduler.shutdown();
    }

    private static class MyTask implements ConflictingRunnable {

        private final int i;

        public MyTask(final int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean hasConflicts(Runnable other) {
            return other instanceof MyTask;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(">>> " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get something like:

```
>>> 0
>>> 11
>>> 21
>>> 31
>>> 42
>>> 53
>>> 64
>>> 75
>>> 86
>>> 97
```

The *ConflictAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* checks for conflicts with already scheduled / running tasks. If a conflict is detected with another scheduled / running task, it won't schedule the other task.